Can a species transition to ZW from XY (or vice versa) sex determination system through evolution?
In my world, there is a species descended from green iguanas (Iguana iguana) that has ZW sex chromosomes rather than XY like all other iguanids.
In the XY sex determination system (which is used by therian mammals, iguanas, olms, Betta splendens, coleopterans, Ginkgo biloba, cannabises, and papayas), the default state is to develop as female (XX), and the father (XY) is the parent that determines the biological sex of the offspring.
In the ZW sex determination system (which is used by birds, anguimorphan squamates, axolotls, tilapias, lepidopterans, Amborella trichopoda, strawberries, and pistachios), the default state is to develop as male (ZZ), and the mother (ZW) is the parent that determines the biological sex of the offspring.
So, is it possible to a species to transition to ZW chromosomes from XY (or vice versa)?

Not only realistic, but totally real!
Apparently, all chordates (or at the very least just vertebrates) had the same sex determination system. Both Teleostei and Lissamphibia have often transitioned to ZW from XY and vice versa. Even mammals apparently historically had ZW before they all currently have XY.
https://www.cell.com/current-biology/fulltext/S0960-9822(06)01996-8

Which proves a basic axiom of evolution: given enough time pretty much anything is possible.

@JBH I think it is more like “Given enough time, pretty much anything that is possible will manifest.”

@SRM That's an entirely fair statement, except that humanity does not know what is possible - only what has happened (at best). As a humorous example, while we might suggest why a one-eyed, one-horned flying purple people eater wouldn't evolve, we don't actually know that it can't.

@JBH We need to wait longer! :-)
